# Extract Attributes using Xpath

Tags: c#, winforms, xpath

I need to extract attributes from an XML file and then add them to a listview.

How do I use Xpath (winforms) to extract attributes:

e.g:

```
<element foo="1" meh="2" lol="3" hi="4">meh</element>
```

How do I extract the data within "foo" and "lol" for example? (So "1" and "3")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/element/@foo
/element/@lol
```

of course if you want to get such nodes from a c# application you need to do something like this:

```
  XmlDocument o = new XmlDocument();
  o.Load(@"c:\file.xml");
  var attribute1 = o.SelectSingleNode("/element/@foo");
```

Comment: in that case don't forget to add the using statement "using System.Xml" in case isn't there already. And please remember to give credit to useful answers! ;)